# How do I filter items from a list and store them in another list?

Tags: python

I have a list with random digits.

```
   nums = [5, 7, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 2, 1, 1, 4, 6]
```

Essentially, I want to multiply each digit by two and if its a double-digit number, filter it out of the list and store it in another list. I know how to do this iteratively, however, I was wondering if there is any interesting way to do this. Like using filter() or another attempt.

Right now I have this:

```
   nums = list(map(lambda x: x * 2, nums))        # multiplies each number by two
   nums = list(filter(lambda x: x < 10, nums))    # keeps only single digit numbers
```

Now, how do I get the numbers that were filtered out (higher than 9)? I know you could always copy the list into a new list and then do two separate filters to get the answer like this:

```
   nums = list(map(lambda x: x * 2, nums))
   temp = nums
   nums = list(filter(lambda x: x < 10, nums))
   temp = list(filter(lambda x: x >= 10, temp))
```

However, is there a way to do this without having to copy the list and use additional memory. I'm not sure if there's some really simple solution that is flying over my head. I'm new to this stuff so, thanks for any help.

Comment: Just make the copy. Even if you did wrote something that removed, say, single-digit numbers from the original list before adding it to a double-digit list, the original list won't actually release any of the freed memory; it will hang on to it to avoid having to allocate more memory later. Just do the simple thing and use what you have; let Python garbage collect any unused memory on its own.

Answer (score 4):

I find list comprehensions are more clean and readable than map and filter in python.

```
nums = [5, 7, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 2, 1, 1, 4, 6]
nums1 = [2*x for x in nums if x < 5]
nums2 = [2*x for x in nums if x >= 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

In `python3`, simple use the `filter` and `map` objects without converting into intermediate lists, also [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) may come handy:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> nums = [5, 7, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 2, 1, 1, 4, 6]
>>> n1, n2 = itertools.tee(map(lambda x: x * 2, nums))
>>> print(list(filter(lambda x: x < 10, n1)))
[2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 8]
>>> print(list(filter(lambda x: x >= 10, n2)))
[10, 14, 10, 12, 14, 16, 12]
>>> next(n1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> next(n2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Check that `tee` make a copy of the iterator that then can be consumed.

**EDIT:**

As @Tomothy32 pointed in the comments, from the `tee` documentation:

> "if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator
>   starts, it is faster to use list() instead of tee()."

So, probably in that case the memory overhead is faster

Comment: As the docs mention, "if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts, it is faster to use `list()` instead of `tee()`." I believe that this is indeed the case here.

Comment: Nor does `map` or any other iterator. I don't understand your point @chepner. May you explain it deeper please? :D

Comment: @Netwave Sorry, completely overlooked that you were mapping the multiplication over the list first, and that's what the two iterators were for.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have accomplished what you were looking for. I just renamed the function that you were trying to retrieve the numbers greater than 10.

`greater = nums = list(filter(lambda x: x >= 10, nums))`

Comment: I think OP is asking for building two separate lists in one go, which this doesn't do it.